# SQL - how do I select one row at a time?

Tags: mysql, perl, select

I would like to perform a certain selection which (as I tested in sqldeveloper) will retrieve a very large amount of data (~350,000 rows). Eventually, I would like to write these rows to a file.

I intend to write a PERL code that does it and I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve one row at a time, write it to my output file and continue to the next row.

That is, I would like to get the same result as my original select but in smaller chunks.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What have you tried? Trying to get smaller chunks out of the DB is usually the wrong way to think about it. Just try to code what you have and see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think you can pay executing your query many times, you can use

```
SELECT .... FROM ...
WHERE ....
LIMIT 0, 100 // index_from, amount
```

first time, adding amount to index next time

```
SELECT .... FROM ...
WHERE ....
LIMIT 100, 100
```

You could use `LIMIT 0,1` to get one record at a time, but you have 350k records... it's crazy!!

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve one row at a time, write it to my output file and continue to the next row.

If you're just trying to export data to a file you should consider using [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html).

It'll run much faster than running each of the queries.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use

```
$dbh->{'mysql_use_result'} = 1;
```

to tell the MySQL driver do not load whole result in memory.

Next you just process each result row with

```
while ( my $ary_ref  = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref ) {

....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a loop

```
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 0, 1
```

And then next time increase your limit with one

```
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1, 1
```